# No puedo parametrizar la cadena de conexion de Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Intente hacer esto que vi en un foto de stackoverflow  para parametrizar la cadena de conexion en EF.
Intente poner la cadena de Conexion desde el contructor del `DbContext`

```
public DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
```

Luego cree este string para que me devuelva la cadena de conexión.

```
   private string GetStringConection()
     {
         var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
         {
             DataSource = "localhost",
             UserID = "sa",
             Password = "1234",
             InitialCatalog = "dbtest"
         };
         return builder.ConnectionString;    
     }
```

Al ejecutar recibo el siguiente error desde EF, he intentado buscar una solucion , pero desconozco el error exacto

**Este es el codigo que uso para probar la ejecucion**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     using (tallerdemecanicaEntities db = new tallerdemecanicaEntities(GetStringConection()))
     {
         var list = db.vta_factura.ToList();
         dataGridView1.DataSource = list;

     }
 }

 private string GetStringConection()
 {
     var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
     {
         DataSource = "localhost",
         UserID = "sa",
         Password = "1234",
         InitialCatalog = "dbtest"
     };
     return builder.ConnectionString;    
 }
```

**Este es el error que obtengo**

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException:
> 'The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was
> generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First
> development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not
> remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use
> Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity
> Framework connection string is included in the app.config or
> web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own
> DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not
> some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the
> base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more
> about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity
> Framework documentation here:
> [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715'](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715%27)